# How to open security page of app (in Settings) programmatically on meizu (FLYME OS)?

Tags: android, security

**Flyme OS** has it's own security page for every app in *Settings->Apps->All* with it's own permission system (even on Android 5), run in background setting etc.
So it's necessary to open this page from the app to allow user change this settings for proper work of app. How to do it?

Comment: important, I'm not talking about how to open application setting on Android, it's exactly about Flyme

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To open **flyme's** security page for your app use following intent:

```
public static void openFlymeSecurityApp(Activity context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.meizu.safe.security.SHOW_APPSEC");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    intent.putExtra("packageName", BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
    try {
        context.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works on MEIZU M5c